# Nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Eu tenho este `SELECT`, onde `m.EmpresaID` pode vir `null`:

```
var pesquisa = from pro in db.Produtos
    join prodempresa in db.ProdutosEmpresas on pro.Id equals prodempresa.ProdutoID 
    into Details from m in Details.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                   Codigo = pro.Codigo,
                   nome = pro.nome,
                   EmpresaID = m.EmpresaID.Value,
                   TipoProduto = pro.TipoProduto,
                   Qtd = m.Qtd
              };
```

Porém quando eu vou adicionar na `list`, mesmo ele sendo declarado como

```
public int? EmpresaID { get; set; }
```

ele retorna este erro.

> InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.

```
foreach (var item in pesquisa)
{
    Estoque produto = new Estoque();

    produto.Codigo = item.Codigo;
    produto.nome = item.nome;
    produto.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;
    produto.TipoProduto = item.TipoProduto;
    produto.Qtd = item.Qtd;
    prod.Add(produto);
}
```

Já tentei comparar o valor, enviar `EmpresaID = m.EmpresaID.GetValueOrDefault(),` porém ocorre o mesmo erro.

Comment: Já tentou atribuir algum valor para `EmpresaID`, mesmo que seja null?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar já sim. E o mesmo erro ocorreu

Comment: Se você tirar essa linha funciona `EmpresaID = m.EmpresaID.Value,`? talvez o `m` já está vindo `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defina um valor padrão  para seu `EmpresaID`

Exemplo:

- `int EmpresaID ?? 0`
- `Guid EmpresaID ?? Guid.Empty`

---

```
var pesquisa = from pro in db.Produtos
    join prodempresa in db.ProdutosEmpresas on pro.Id equals prodempresa.ProdutoID 
    into Details from m in Details.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
            Codigo = pro.Codigo,
            nome = pro.nome,
            EmpresaID = m.EmpresaID ?? 0,
            TipoProduto = pro.TipoProduto,
            Qtd = m.Qtd
        };
```

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado.